# Typescript - Access class property from within object's function

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make the following working in Angular component:

class property:

```
prop1 = false;
```

public method:

```
public method1() {
   const obj1 = {
      event: {
         if (this.prop1 ... // doesn't work - undefined
      }
   }

}
```

My question is it possible to access class properties from within an object declared in a method?

Thanks

Comment: I suggest you post a minimal but complete and reproducible example of what is going on. From your abbreviated example, I don't think we can help you (is `this` undefined, is `this.prop1` undefined, where is `method1`, how is it called).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining an object. The value of your object property event is not a method so if(this. should result in a typescript error.

You can define methods in your object with access to the class scope by using arrow function or .bind(this).

Example:

```
 const obj1 = {
  event: () => {
     if (this.prop1) {
       console.log(this.prop1)
     } else {
       console.log(this.prop1)
     }
  }
}

// and call the method
obj1.event()
```

Your goal with this code is probably very different, but the reason why your code is not working is because an object property value is not a function body.